# Repeated content when moved with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Whenever I try to move content using the code below I am getting repeated content at target position. The problem I am facing is that there are four instances of the same html structure but the page is in php using WordPress loop. In fact they are last four recent posts. I tried :first selector but the content is repeated.

How can I extract that content and place only one instance at target position? Solution with hiding repeated content using css display:none is not a good idea. I think this is possible using jQuery.

```
    <div class="target">
    <p>target position</p>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
    <p>Some other content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third">
    <p>content1</p>
    <p>content2</p>
    <p>content3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third">
    <p>content1</p>
    <p>content2</p>
    <p>content3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third">
    <p>content1</p>
    <p>content2</p>
    <p>content3</p>
    </div>


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.one-third p:first').insertAfter('.target');
    });
```

Here is jsfiddle for help: 
https://jsfiddle.net/f4skoLv7/6/

Comment: what is your desired output? you need only one content1 at target ?

Comment: @Kiranramchandran yes, I need only one instance of content1 at target location

Comment: @Radi please try this.  $('.one-third :first').insertAfter('.target');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code will work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.one-third p:first').insertAfter('.target');
 });
```

this will show only one `content1` in the target location.

if you want to show all content then try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one-third:first').insertAfter('.target');
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcfn0xk/)

[DEMO TO SHOW ALL DATA](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcfn0xk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

So here are two possible corrections to your issue:

1. If you want to remove the first p element from the first .one-third div and place it under the .target element you simply would need to do this with your jquery code:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('.one-third:first p:first-child').insertAfter('.target');
> });
> ```

2. If you simply want to copy the first p element from the first .one-third div to place under .target you would do this with your jquery code:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('.one-third:first p:first-child').clone().insertAfter('.target');
>  });
> ```

Hope this helps!